# Inconsistent date string parsing by Date().toISOString() in V8

Tags: javascript, date, date-formatting, date-parsing, toisostring

Paying with `new Date().toISOString()`, I observe an inconsistency in parsing of **the same** date in different string formats: `2020-01-01` and `2020/01/01`:

```js
const opt1 = new Date("2020-01-01").toISOString();
document.write(`"2020-01-01": <b>${opt1}</b>`);

document.write("<br />");

const opt2 = new Date("2020/01/01").toISOString();
document.write(`"2020/01/01": <b>${opt2}</b>`);
```

I'm just curious, why `2020-01-01` and `2020/01/01` are parsed differently?

Comment: One of them is in GMT, the other is in the local timezone.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, great, that's even more detailed explanation with a short leap in a JS-history.

Comment: If you want to know why YYYY-MM-DD is treated as UTC, the answer is in the TC39 deliberations recorded [here](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/87). Short answer: commercial interests won over common sense.